# How do I map the root without overwriting other paths with koa-mount?

Tags: koa

I have the following structure...

```
- static
  - dashboard.html
```

But when I use the following...

```
mainApp.use(mount('/', async (ctx)=>{
    ...
    ctx.body = await pug.render('index', {
      user: userInfo
    }, true);
}));
mainApp.use(mount('/static', serve(__dirname+"/static")));
```

But when I run it returns the pug render and not the html file in the static folder. If I comment out...

```
// mainApp.use(mount('/', async (ctx)=>{
//     ...
//     ctx.body = await pug.render('index', {
//       user: userInfo
//     }, true);
// }));
mainApp.use(mount('/static', serve(__dirname+"/static")));
```

I can get the static file but now there is nothing rendering at root.

Answer (score 0):

you are using template engine the wrong way; use koa-views:

```
const views = require('koa-views');
const router = require('@koa/router')();

const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

// middleware

app.use(views('./views'), {
  map: { html: 'pug' }
}));

// route definitions

router.get('/', list)

app.use(router.routes());

async function list(ctx) {
  await ctx.render('list', { posts: posts });
}
```